# Determine for what range of values of $a$ the equilibrium point at $x=(0,0)$ is stable

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x'=$ $\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & -2 \\
    a       & -5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$x$

Determine for what range of values of $a$ the equilibrium point at $x=(0,0)$
is stable.

I don't know really where to start since there are so many cases (complex, repeated, etc)

Comment: @Crostul : Ick. Worst advice I've seen here in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & -2 \\
    a       & -5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we have: $D=\det (A)= 5+2a$ and $T=\mbox{tr}(A)=-6$
so the characteristic polynomial is
$$
P(\lambda)=\lambda^2-T\lambda+D=\lambda^2+6\lambda+5+2a
$$
that has solutions
$$
\lambda_{1,2}=-3\pm\sqrt{2(2-a)}
$$

We know ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory#Linear_autonomous_systems)) that $(0,0)$ is asymptotically  stable for $t\to \infty$ iff the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ are  $\le 0$.

This is done for $a>2$, since we have two complex conjugate eigenvalues with the $\Re(\lambda_{1,2})=-3$.

For $a<2$ we have two real eigenvalues, one of which is negative and the other is negative if
$$
-3+\sqrt{2(2-a)}<0 \Rightarrow a>-\frac{5}{2}
$$
for $a=-\frac{5}{2}$ we have one eigenvalue $=0$ and the other negative.

So: $(0,0)$ is  stable for $t\to \infty$ for any value of $a\ge -\frac{5}{2}$, and it is asymptotically  stable for $a> -\frac{5}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

I think you really have to do some case work here.

First, a couple of useful facts: The sum of the eigenvalues of a matrix equals the sum of the diagonal entries of the matrix (here, $(-1)+(-5)=-6$), and the product of the eigenvalues is the determinant of the matrix (here, $5+2a$.)

If the eigenvalues are real and $(0,0)$ is stable, you can't have a saddle; those are always unstable. Hence the eigenvalues have the same sign (which must be negative, since their sum is negative). Their product is therefore positive, which means the determinant is also positive.

If the eigenvalues are complex, they are $a+bi$ and $a-bi$. Their sum once again is $2a=-6$, so $a=-3$, so the real part is negative, which means $(0,0)$ will be stable.

Hence, you have stability if (a) both eigenvalues are real and $5+2a\ge0$, or (b) both eigenvalues are complex. You can compute the eigenvalues explicitly in terms of $a$ [so maybe Crostul's advice isn't all that bad] to find the appropriate conditions on $a$.